# Arduino Parse data serially on VB

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, visualstudio

I am working with Arduino Uno, I have tracker application running on Arduino Uno board. I am sending data in comma separated value. Now I want to view data into Visual Basic. I have code as below. The below code is working with fake values but as soon it live stream data split functions gives out error.

Serial output data looks like this.

```
Start,Latitude:13.00,longitude:60.00,MODE:1,DIR:1,Local Date:0/0/0,Local Time:5:30:2,tracker_des_angle:0.00,tracker_actual_pos:57.22,Wind Speed :0.00,END
Start,Latitude:13.00,longitude:60.00,MODE:1,DIR:1,Local Date:0/0/0,Local Time:5:30:4,tracker_des_angle:43.00,tracker_actual_pos:69.20,Wind Speed :0.95,END
Start,Latitude:13.00,longitude:60.00,MODE:1,DIR:0,Local Date:0/0/0,Local Time:5:30:6,tracker_des_angle:43.00,tracker_actual_pos:16.34,Wind Speed :1.85,END
Start,Latitude:13.00,longitude:60.00,MODE:1,DIR:0,Local Date:0/0/0,Local Time:5:30:8,tracker_des_angle:43.00,tracker_actual_pos:11.89,Wind Speed :2.77,END
```

visual basic code:

```
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Text


Public Class Solar_Track
    Dim comPORT As String
    Dim receivedData As String = ""
    Dim strArray() As String
    Dim Data As String
    Dim latitude() As String
    Dim longitude() As String
    Dim Local_date() As String
    Dim Local_Time() As String
    Dim Mode_oper() As String
    Dim Dir_motor() As String
    Dim Act_pos() As String
    Dim Dis_pos() As String
    Dim wind_pos() As String
    Dim start As Boolean
    Dim End_Result As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean

    Sub Parse_receivedata(ByVal msg As String)

        RichTextBox1.Text &= msg
        Data = msg

        strArray = Split(Data, ",")
        latitude = Split(strArray(1), ":")
        Text_Latitude.Text = latitude(1)

        longitude = Split(strArray(2), ":")
        Text_Longitude.Text = longitude(1)

        Mode_oper = Split(strArray(3), ":")
        Text_Mode.Text = Mode_oper(1)

        Dir_motor = Split(strArray(4), ":")
        Text_MotorDir.Text = Dir_motor(1)

        Local_date = Split(strArray(5), ":")
        Text_LocalDate.Text = Local_date(1)

        Local_Time = Split(strArray(6), ":")
        Label_hour.Text = Local_Time(1)
        Label_min.Text = Local_Time(2)
        Label_Sec.Text = Local_Time(3)

        Dis_pos = Split(strArray(7), ":")
        Text_TrackerDesire.Text = Dis_pos(1)

        Act_pos = Split(strArray(8), ":")
        Text_TrackerActual.Text = Act_pos(1)

        wind_pos = Split(strArray(9), ":")
        Text_Windspeed.Text = wind_pos(1)


    End Sub


    Sub data_parse()
        Data = "Start,Latitude:13.00,longitude:60.00,MODE:1,DIR:1,Local Date:0/0/0,Local Time:5:30:2,tracker_des_angle:0.00,tracker_actual_pos:54.48,Wind Speed :0.00,END"
        strArray = Split(Data, ",")

        latitude = Split(strArray(1), ":")
        Text_Latitude.Text = latitude(1)

        longitude = Split(strArray(2), ":")
        Text_Longitude.Text = longitude(1)

        Mode_oper = Split(strArray(3), ":")
        Text_Mode.Text = Mode_oper(1)

        Dir_motor = Split(strArray(4), ":")
        Text_MotorDir.Text = Dir_motor(1)

        Local_date = Split(strArray(5), ":")
        Text_LocalDate.Text = Local_date(1)

        Local_Time = Split(strArray(6), ":")
        Label_hour.Text = Local_Time(1)
        Label_min.Text = Local_Time(2)
        Label_Sec.Text = Local_Time(3)

        Dis_pos = Split(strArray(7), ":")
        Text_TrackerDesire.Text = Dis_pos(1)

        Act_pos = Split(strArray(8), ":")
        Text_TrackerActual.Text = Act_pos(1)

        wind_pos = Split(strArray(9), ":")
        Text_Windspeed.Text = wind_pos(1)


    End Sub


    Private Sub Solar_Track_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        comPORT = ""
        For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
            comPort_ComboBox.Items.Add(sp)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles comPort_ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (comPort_ComboBox.SelectedItem <> "") Then
            comPORT = comPort_ComboBox.SelectedItem
        End If
    End Sub




    Private Sub BtConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles connect_BTN.Click
        If (connect_BTN.Text = "Connect") Then
            If (comPORT <> "") Then
                SerialPort1.Close()
                SerialPort1.PortName = comPORT
                SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
                SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
                SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
                SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
                SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
                SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
                SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 10000

                SerialPort1.Open()
                connect_BTN.Text = "Dis-connect"
                Timer1.Enabled = True
                Timer_LBL.Text = "Timer: ON"

            Else
                MsgBox("Select a COM port first")
            End If
        Else
            SerialPort1.Close()
            connect_BTN.Text = "Connect"
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Timer_LBL.Text = "Timer: OFF"
        End If


    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
        ''RichTextBox1.Text &= receivedData
        Parse_receivedata(receivedData)
        receivedData = ""
        '' data_parse()
    End Sub
    Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
        Dim Incoming As String
        Try
            Incoming = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                Return "nothing" & vbCrLf
            Else
                Return Incoming
            End If
        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            Return "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
        End Try

    End Function

    Private Sub BtClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtClear.Click
        RichTextBox1.Text = ""
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Posting your question twice doesn't make it more fit for the Arduino community. Flagging it as duplicate AND off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a timer to regularly read the data from the serial port... I think you'd be better using the `DataReceived()` event of the SerialPort class.

The other thing is that you are just reading whatever data is in the buffer (with `ReadExisting`) if all that is in the buffer is 2 or 3 characters (not a full line) then your `Parse_receivedata()` will not be able to split it based on `,`

You want to keep appending the received data to a StringBuilder (or similar) until you hit a CR/LF and then pass it to the `Parse_receivedata()` function:

Psuedo code would be something like:

```
// class scoped variable
rxData = ""

...
// inside the DataReceived() event
rxData += SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
If (rxData.Contains(Environment.Newline)) Then
  lines = rxData.Split(Environment.NewLine)
  toParse = lines[0]
  rxData = lines[1]
  ParseRxData(toParse)
End If
```